# how to preform out.println in declared function in servlet?

Tags: java, servlets

I have a declaration servlet:

```
<%!
private static void printMyLine(String line){
     out.println(line);
}
%>

<%
     printMyLine("this is my line");
%>
```

but I get a bug at runtime saying "out cannot be resolved".
when i execute the same code without the function in a regular servlet, it works fine:

```
 <%
     out.println("this is my line");
 %>
```

Can anyone please help?
Thank you!

Comment: sorry but <% is for jsp.... did you mean jsp? if yes change the tag...

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be using scriptlets; they are being phased out. You should move onto JSTL instead.

You can also access the `out` stream from the `HttpResponse` object.

**Example**

```
OutputStream os = response.getOutputStream();

os.print("Hello".getBytes());
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, out is a implicit object in jsp. But it is not a static object. You are using the 'out' in static method. But we cannot use instance objects in static methods. Once you remove the static keyword to the method and try. It will work.

I guess it helps.

Answer (score 0):

JSP implicit objects can not be accessible in declarations. These objects available only within generated servlet's service() method.

Answer (score 0):

On `doPost` or `doGet` methods in your Servlet use your `printMyLine` method on this way:

```
response.setContentType("text/html"); 
try {
    out=response.getWriter();
} catch (IOException io) {
    System.out.println("Hello exception");
}
out.println("Printed from Servlet");
```

You'll have to change the printMyLine declaration to this:

```
private void printMyLine(HttpServletResponse response, String message)
```

Finally, you'll get:

```
private void printMyLine(HttpServletResponse response, String message) {
    response.setContentType("text/html"); 
    try {
        out=resp.getWriter();
    } catch (IOException io) {
        System.out.println("Hello exception");
    }
    out.println(message);
    out.flush();
    out.close();
}
```